# Why does this not print a double?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class Test {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        double d = 4.0;
        double p = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(d + p); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a Console.Read(); after WriteLine so the program will halt long enough for you to view the screen.

Comment: Make sure to halt the program, the code will work just fine.

Comment: Sorry guys im not sure i understand,but if this helps e.g if i input 4.0 or 4 it prints an integer so in this case 8 regardless of my input as a decimal or an integer. im new to programming.thank you for the responses

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((d + p).ToString("0.##%"));`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Console.WriteLine((d + p).ToString("N"));
```

This will print two decimal places. If you want 3 decimal places, just edit the 'N' part:

```
Console.WriteLine((d + p).ToString("N3"));
```

Comment: This does not in any way answer OP's concern about printing "8" instead if "8.00".

Comment: Ooops sorry. I misunderstood OP's question. I updated my answer now.

Comment: I think OP also misunderstood they own question till they get first comments and answers :) so you are not alone there.